# assign a javascript object changing some properties with 1 istruction

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have this javascript istruction (useing lodash):

```
list = _.reduce(list, (acc, next, index) => {
    acc.push({
        key: index,
        data: next
    });
    return acc;
}, []);
```

What I need to do is changing some properties of the "next" object before assigning to the "data" object.
Specifically I need to format a time property (called "start_time") and add another property to the "data" object.

**UPDATED**

This is how the "next" object is:

```
next = {
    id: "1",
    start_time: "20:00:00",
    title: "Example"
}
```

What I need is a new object like this:

```
next = {
    key: "new_key" // NEW PROPERTIES ADDED TO THE OBJECT
    id: "1",
    start_time: "20:00", // THIS PROPERTIES HAS BEEN FORMATTED
    title: "Example"
}
```

The new object will be assigned to the "data" property of the new item added to "acc" array.
Is it possible to do with 1 instruction useing ES2015 or lodash?

**SOLVED**

I solved it useing this code (Object.assign and map together):

```
list = _.reduce(list, (acc, next, index) => {
    next = next.map(function(item) {
        return Object.assign({}, item, {key: new_key, start_time: format_date});
    });

    acc.push({
        key: index,
        data: next
    });
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Thanks

Comment: please add some data to the question.

Comment: Looks like `map` would be more appropriate than `reduce` in this case.

Comment: I do not know javascript so deep, if you can help me optimizing this code I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `Object.assign()`. It takes a base object and then merges it with one or more other objects, overwriting the corresponding fields:

`Object.assign({}, next, {key: myKey, start_time: format(next.start_time)})`

Note that it's idiomatic to start with a bare new object `{}` to avoid mutating your existing objects.

Comment: Good advice, I guess its what I was looking for. But I realized that the "next" variable is not an object, but an array of objects. So I need to use your code for all "next" items.